# Delete an image from Cloudinary using REST full api

Tags: cloudinary

How can I delete an image from my cloudinary server using simple REST api? though I'm able to upload an image successfully but couldn't find a proper way to delete the same using api

Answer (score 3):

If you're using one of the Cloudinary server-side SDKs then you can delete a resource from Cloudinary using the [destroy](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_method) method of the Upload API.

If you're making a direct call to the API then you can use cURL. For example, to delete the image with public_id `sample_image` from cloud `my_cloud` I can do the following.

Export all required variables:

```
export CLD_NAME=my_cloud
export CLD_API_KEY=12345
export CLD_API_SECRET=abcde
```

Generate the signature:

```
export TIME=$(date +%s)

export SIGNATURE=$(echo -n "invalidate=true&public_id=sample_image&timestamp=$TIME$CLD_API_SECRET" | openssl sha1)
```

```
curl -X POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/$CLD_NAME/image/destroy --data "invalidate=true&public_id=sample_image&timestamp=$TIME&signature=$SIGNATURE&api_key=$CLD_API_KEY"
```

For more information regarding direct API calls please see this section of the documentation - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures

Comment: I need a simple RESTful api that I can call through Postman client

Comment: how to do this is js

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya - Signature generation should not be done on the client-side as it requires the API Secret which should not be exposed in client-side code. If you want to use NodeJS on the server-side, then we recommend using the [NodeJS SDK](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#using_cloudinary_backend_sdks_to_generate_sha_authentication_signatures) and the dedicated `api_sign_request` method.

Comment: @Khawar For Postman collections, please see:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/using_cloudinary_postman_collections

Comment: @Aleksandar How can I delete an image in cloudinary in Nextjs? Here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73506019/14835590

Comment: @Nasem - I added a comment on your post.

Answer (score -1):

When you upload the image,public_id shoud be saved in the database. Otherwise, you can't delete images using URL. I tried in React Js to upload images.

``

```
onClickHandler = () => {
        const data = new FormData()
        for(var x = 0; x<this.state.selectedFile.length; x++) {
            data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile[x])
            data.append("upload_preset","*****")
            data.append("cloud_name","*****")
            axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/*****/image/upload",data)
              .then((res) => {
                  console.log(res.data);
                console.log(res.data);
                const imageDetails={
                    image:res.data.secure_url,
                    public_id:res.data.public_id,
                    productName:"*******"
                }
                axios.post("http://localhost:4000/*********",imageDetails)
                .then(res=>console.log(res))
              })
        }
```

``
Then you can delete images using node js. refer the below link to get node js code
[Delete cloudinary images in node js](https://dev.to/itsmefarhan/cloudinary-files-images-crud-operations-with-nodejs-express-multer-2147)

Comment: Can you please be precise of the answer , the uploading i have been through , i just need the deletion

Comment: Can you please share me the code of deleting , public_id and url already stored in the database

Comment: `const deleteProduct = async(req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.id;

    console.log(productId);
    let product;
    try {
        product = await Product.findById(productId);
        await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(product.public_id);
        res.send("cloud image deleted")

    } catch (err) {
        res.send({ err });
    }
    try {
        await product.remove();
        res.send("Image deleted")
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({ err });
    }

}`