# How to delete cloudinary image file with axios in Nextjs?

Tags: axios, next.js, cloudinary

I'm trying to delete an image file uploaded to cloudinary with Next.js.

The file gets uploaded just fine. In the `uploadImage` function I save the public_id, signature in the `imageData` state. I also save the API key of my cloud there.

Then I tried to delete the newly uploaded image with a post request using axios like this:

```
const res = await axios.post(
  "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/destroy",
  formData
);
```

It results in a post error. I also tried it with `const res = await axios.delete()`. It doesn't work either.

How can I delete the image?

```
export default function Home() {
  const [img, setImg] = useState("");
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState({
    url: "",
    public_id: "",
    signature: "",
    api_key: "",
  });

  const updateImage = (e) => {
    setImg(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const uploadImage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", img);
    data.append("upload_preset", "cloudinary_default");
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/upload`,
        data
      );
      setImageData({
        url: response.data.url,
        public_id: response.data.public_id,
        signature: response.data.signature,
        api_key: <my_api_key>,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error from axios post`, error);
    }
  };

  const deleteImage2 = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime()
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("public_id", imageData.public_id);
    formData.append("signature", imageData.signature);
    formData.append("api_key", imageData.api_key);
    formData.append("timestamp",timestamp)
    const res = await axios.post(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/destroy",
      formData
    );
    console.log("response from delete: ", res);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="file" onChange={updateImage} />
        <button onClick={uploadImage}>Upload</button>
        <button onClick={deleteImage}>Remove</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edited: response from `uploadImage`

```
data: {
  access_mode: "public"
  asset_id: "a2cfdb456108e23d154520f913e1b5d5"
  bytes: 635033
  created_at: "2022-08-27T08:32:13Z"
  etag: "5d2518ce194a66abd33a9a966a86350e"
  folder: ""
  format: "jpg"
  height: 4167
  original_filename: "asdf.png"
  placeholder: false
  public_id: "uk66y5akqeyfyiwebxed"
  resource_type: "image"
  secure_url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud_name>/image/upload/v1661589133/uk66y5akqeyfyiw 
 ebxed.jpg"
  signature: "cc836688d98fae0d57b629e2d402c6a670217d95"
}
```

Comment: What is the exact response from Cloudinary you receive when sending that request?
I notice that you're providing a signature but not sending the timestamp in your request so the first thing to correct would be to pass the timestamp from the signature generation in your destroy() call formData.

Comment: @Aleksandar the signature I'm adding is from the newly uploaded image response. I updated my description and added the timestamp like this: `const timestamp = new Date().getTime()` and `formData.append("timestamp",timestamp)`. Just after I uploaded a new image file, I tried to delete that image but it shows the same post error. It also says unauthorized. What did I did wrong?

Comment: @Aleksandar When I click the remove button after uploading the image, there shows two errors. The first is `POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/nhnasem/image/destroy 401 (Unauthorized)` and the second one is `Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'`

Comment: The signature you receive in the upload response is not to be used by passing it in any other API calls. What you need to do is generate your own signature (on your backend server), send that to your frontend and include it in the formData. The signature is based on the parameters you're passing in the API call to Cloudinary you want to make. Please see the following section with instructions on how you can generate a valid authentication signature - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures

Comment: @Aleksandar Do I need to generate my own signature when doing a signed upload? What other parameters do I need to pass in formdata for a signed upload?

Comment: @Aleksandar Can you please look at this question of mine about cloudinary? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73580900/14835590

Comment: Yes, any Signed request you want to make to Cloudinary (upload, destroy etc) would need a valid signature which you would create. If you are using one of Cloudinary's backend SDKs (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_sdks#backend) to make those API calls then that will be handled for you automatically. If you don't want to use one of Cloudinary's SDKs then you would need to handle the signature generation yourself in your own code.

Comment: @Aleksandar I'm not using Cloudinary's SDKs. When destroying an asset in the cloudinary (one that already exists), generating signature seems easy because there's already a public_id available in the image data. But when uploading a new image, there's no public_id that I can put into the signature. The question I asked you to look at throws me an error of invalid signature. How can I make that not happen?

Comment: In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73580900/14835590, I tried appending the image file, signed upload preset, API key, timestamp and signature then send the post request to the API: `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud-name>/image/upload/`. I generated the API using the same method for deletion. But it doesn't work either.

Comment: API Key should not be part of the string to sign to generate the signature. Please see this page (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures) which mentions the parameters that should not be included in a signature generation - also the order of parameters being signed matters too. If making this change does not resolve it then I'd recommend, as Loic mentioned in the comment on the other post, for you to contact Cloudinary support (by emailing support@cloudinary.com) and share the exact string you are trying to sign and your upload code.

Comment: Also, you don't need to always sign the public_id. The signature should include the parameters you will be sending to Cloudinary for that API call you want to make (apart from API Key, File, Cloud Name and Resource Type which should not be used in signature generation entirely). So, if you're not passing public_id as part of your upload then you should not include it in your signature generation.